# How to subsitute symbols in sympyfied expression properly?

Tags: python, sympy

my goal is to have a string turned into a symbolic expression using sympify and then make substitutions.

```
import sympy as sp

Eq_Str = 'a*x+b'
Eq_Sym = sp.sympify(Eq_Str)
```

Then, for instance, substitute `a` for something else:

```
Eq_Sym.subs(a,2)
```

But I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-5-e9892d6ffa06>", line 1, in <module>
    Eq_Sym.subs(a,2)

NameError: name 'a' is not defined
```

I understand that there is no symbol `a` in the workspace. Am I right?
Is there a way to get the symbols from the set I get from `Eq_Sym.free_symbols` into the workspace so I can substitute them in `Eq_Sym`.

Thank you very much for taking the time to read this.

Comment: Typically, symbols are defined ahead of time `a, b, x = symbols('a b x')`.  That would give you the programmer more control than if you took them from an equation string like this.

Comment: How sticking with strings:  `Eq_Sym.subs(symbols('a'),2)` or `Eq_Sym.subs(sympify('a'),2)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `globals()` for that:

```
import sympy as sp

Eq_Str = 'a*x+b'
Eq_Sym = sp.sympify(Eq_Str)
for s in Eq_Sym.free_symbols :
    globals()[s.name] = s;
print (Eq_Sym.subs(a,2)); #b + 2*x
```